# Changing the cursor appearance in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing the Notes application and I placed the `UITextView` on the "Adding notes screen". But the cursor doesn't appears in the top left corner of the `UITextView`.

See the link to the screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCYBb.png]

See the link to the source code https://github.com/vladislavlev/notes

Thank you in advance. I would be eternally grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be only one text view exists in your view controller and add this in inspector

[image]

Adjust scrollview insets to **true** it will work .